# Mule with Java EE application

Tags: mule, esb

I added a jsp page to my mule application using jetty connector and it's working well. I read that mule support Java EE application due to his embedded jetty server but when i try to add a servlet page i can't arrive to put it in the correct place i tried src folder also the src/main/java but nothing worked. Any help, guide, advice or tutorial i'll be grateful.

When i run my application with putting the servler in src/controller i get this error:

```
INFO  2015-04-16 16:04:16,580 [main] org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector: 
**********************************************************************
* Will deploy a web app at http://localhost:8093/mule                *
**********************************************************************
WARN  2015-04-16 16:04:16,708 [main] org.eclipse.jetty: Controller.MAJDevice
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Controller.MAJDevice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:175)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:134)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector.doStart(JettyHttpConnector.java:312)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$2.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:465)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$2.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:459)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at org.mule.transport.ConnectorLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(ConnectorLifecycleManager.java:59)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.startAfterConnect(AbstractConnector.java:458)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1604)
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1621)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:424)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector$3.onNotification(JettyHttpConnector.java:237)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector$3.onNotification(JettyHttpConnector.java:227)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Sender.dispatch(Sender.java:38)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Policy.dispatch(Policy.java:118)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.notifyListeners(ServerNotificationManager.java:245)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.fireNotification(ServerNotificationManager.java:196)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.fireNotification(DefaultMuleContext.java:469)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:282)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:123)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:274)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:294)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:158)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:220)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:272)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:147)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
WARN  2015-04-16 16:04:16,714 [main] org.eclipse.jetty: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Controller.MAJDevice
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector.doStart(JettyHttpConnector.java:312)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$2.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:465)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$2.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:459)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at org.mule.transport.ConnectorLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(ConnectorLifecycleManager.java:59)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.startAfterConnect(AbstractConnector.java:458)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1604)
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1621)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:424)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector$3.onNotification(JettyHttpConnector.java:237)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector$3.onNotification(JettyHttpConnector.java:227)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Sender.dispatch(Sender.java:38)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Policy.dispatch(Policy.java:118)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.notifyListeners(ServerNotificationManager.java:245)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.fireNotification(ServerNotificationManager.java:196)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.fireNotification(DefaultMuleContext.java:469)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:282)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:123)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:274)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:294)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:158)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:220)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:272)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:147)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
WARN  2015-04-16 16:04:16,715 [main] org.eclipse.jetty: FAILED Miseajour: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Controller.MAJDevice
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Controller.MAJDevice
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector.doStart(JettyHttpConnector.java:312)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$2.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:465)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$2.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:459)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at org.mule.transport.ConnectorLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(ConnectorLifecycleManager.java:59)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.startAfterConnect(AbstractConnector.java:458)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1604)
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1621)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:424)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector$3.onNotification(JettyHttpConnector.java:237)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector$3.onNotification(JettyHttpConnector.java:227)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Sender.dispatch(Sender.java:38)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Policy.dispatch(Policy.java:118)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.notifyListeners(ServerNotificationManager.java:245)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.fireNotification(ServerNotificationManager.java:196)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.fireNotification(DefaultMuleContext.java:469)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:282)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:123)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:274)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:294)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:158)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:220)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:272)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:147)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
WARN  2015-04-16 16:04:16,819 [main] org.eclipse.jetty: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/mule,file:/D:/Ab%20Cours/PFE/workspace/.mule/apps/webesb/webapps/mule/},D:\Ab Cours\PFE\workspace\.mule\apps\webesb\webapps\mule
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Controller.MAJDevice
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector.doStart(JettyHttpConnector.java:312)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$2.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:465)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$2.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:459)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at org.mule.transport.ConnectorLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(ConnectorLifecycleManager.java:59)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.startAfterConnect(AbstractConnector.java:458)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1604)
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1621)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:424)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector$3.onNotification(JettyHttpConnector.java:237)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyHttpConnector$3.onNotification(JettyHttpConnector.java:227)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Sender.dispatch(Sender.java:38)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Policy.dispatch(Policy.java:118)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.notifyListeners(ServerNotificationManager.java:245)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.fireNotification(ServerNotificationManager.java:196)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.fireNotification(DefaultMuleContext.java:469)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:282)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:123)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:274)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:294)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:158)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:220)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:272)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:147)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the following in your Mule config :-

```
<jetty:connector name="jettyConnector">
   <jetty:webapps directory="${app.home}/webapps" port="8083"/>
</jetty:connector>
```

Please go through these link to understand the implementation of Jetty :-
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Jetty+Transport+Reference

and

[Jetty in Mule only works in earlier version of Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892731/jetty-in-mule-only-works-in-earlier-version-of-studio)

and

[Can Mule run a JavaEE web-application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439944/can-mule-run-a-javaee-web-application)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did what i mentioned but my problem now is where to put my servlet pages.

Comment: Put your web-app in src/main/app

Comment: Follow the steps to get an idea to implement web application in Mule .. also check the folder structure there :- http://www.slideshare.net/anir37/web-application-with-mule?qid=e234e188-ace2-4725-ab72-8430710c1a24&v=qf1&b=&from_search=1

Comment: The servlet pages will be in same structure as used to be in web application in web app